# How Can I Troubleshoot An Unauthorised Error With AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

**Use Case:** I desire to delete a DynamoDB record with a mutation as an `owner` of the record using AWS Amplify, GraphQL and Typescript.

**Note**:

1. All changes have successfully deployed and built in the AWS Amplify Pipeline as a full-stack build with CI/CD
2. I am logged in as the owner of the record.
3. I have used `console.log` to ensure the values are obtained before the `await` function is ran.

**Front-End Query:**

```
await API.graphql({
  query: deleteImage,
  variables: {
    input: { 
      id          : fileName,
      employerID  : Auth.user.attributes["custom:id"],
     },
    },
    authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
});
```

**GraphQL Schema:**

```
type Image
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete, read] }
    ]
```

**GraphQL Mutation:**

```
export const deleteImage = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation DeleteImage(
    $input: DeleteImageInput!
    $condition: ModelImageConditionInput
  ) {
    deleteImage(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
      id
      owner
      name
      contentType
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      employerID
    }
  }
`;
```

**Error Message:**

`"Not Authorized to access deleteImage on type Mutation"`

Answer (score 0):

The `unauthorized` error may occur misleadingly when the record in the DynamoDB table does not exist.

Check your table to see whether the record exists, as this may be the cause.